# How is Orochimaru able to use his arms?

Tags: naruto

How is Orochimaru able to use his arms? Didn't the 3rd hokage cut them out of his spirit?
So even if he did jump between bodies, he shouldn't be able to use his hands because it wasn't his physical body's arms that were cut but spiritual ones.

Answer (score 3):

Orochimaru prior to he 4th Shinbo War

---

If you are referring to Orochimaru before the war he was unable to use ninjutsu. Hiruzen used the reaper death seal to take the part of Orochimarus soul that contained his arms.

---

Orochimaru during the 4th Shinobi War: This answer contains spoilers.

> [Orochimaru](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru) regains the use of his arms after he summons the shinigami ?>! and cuts open its stomach releasing the trapped part of his soul.
>  "Orochimaru proceeded to don the mask which invoked the Shinigami to
>   possess his body. Orochimaru then proceeded to cut open the
>   Shinigami's stomach, a wound reflected on his own body, to release the
>   trapped contents inside the Shinigami."
>  "With his arms restored as well."
>  Also before the Shinigami was able to trap Orochimarus soul he switched places with a white Zetsu allowing him to escape.
>  "To escape death, Orochimaru transferred his being in the White Zetsu Suigetsu was holding down"