# How was Orochimaru able to jump bodies?

Tags: naruto

During the attack on the Leaf Village by the Sand and Sound Ninja, Orochimaru revealed he had learned the Jutsu that allowed him to jump bodies and thus achieve a form of immortality. during their fight Hiruzen Sarutobi used the Reaper Death Seal Jutsu to seal away Orochimaru's arms and thus taking away his Jutsu.

Near to the end of Naruto before the Time Jump to Shippuden, Orochimaru tried waiting for Sasuke to reach him but in the end had to jump to another body but [according to this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/29103/1587)

> Orochimaru regained his arms during the 4th Shinobi War, well into Shippuden

so if Orochimari couldn't use Jutsu before the time skip into Shippuden, how was he able to jump bodies?

Answer (score 7):

Despite the Reaper Death Seal immobilizing Orochimaru's arms, he could still perform justu that did not require hand signs.

> [...] Though the act undid most of the damage caused by the Dead Demon Consuming Seal, it still left Orochimaru incapable of using techniques requiring hand seals.

Orochimaru was able to jump bodies because the justu required does not require handle signs. How it is performed is not shown until much later in the Shippuden series, which is detailed below with a spoiler

> To perform this technique, Orochimaru reveals his true form: a gigantic white snake composed of smaller white snakes, by abandoning his current host's body. Orochimaru then swallows the new host and takes him or her to a separate, mental plane where he envelops the mind of his victim. The snake body then dies and falls apart, and Orochimaru's soul dominates the body
>  <sub>[Living Corpse Reincarnation](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Corpse_Reincarnation)</sub>